# Implementing usage analytics in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, analytics

I want to implement some analytics for my rails web application, e.g.:-

Who's using the app?
How often they are using?
What content in the app are the users viewing?

Can anyone please suggest me a Ruby gem or any way to start working on this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may mention you some names. Very useful tools that I use. 
[Clicky](http://clicky.com/)
[Chartbeat](https://chartbeat.com/)
[Woopra](https://www.woopra.com/)...

There are many more available, but i like these three the most ! :)